# adding and removing items keeping control of the counter and text list append

Tags: jquery

okay, if anyone can help me in fixing my code:

I had good progress in making it worth work where i can add and delete the elements and counter seem to be resetting

The issue is here:

I ca start adding the Items, they get increments by 1,2,3,4,5

Then i will delete item 2,3 - It will reset it to 1,2,3 [so far so good]

Then i add another one and it starts from 1,2,3,5 - see it starts from 5 rather than 4 [That is what needs a fix:]

Here is my Compete complete

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cnt = 1;
$("body").on("click", ".delrow", function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $('.newrow'+id).remove();
        cnt--;
        resetStuff();
});
function resetStuff() {
    cnt = 2;
    $(".delrow").each(function() {
        $(this).parent().attr('class','newrow'+cnt);
        $(this).attr('data-id',cnt);
        $(this).parent().find('input:text').each(function() {
            var ids = $(this).parent().find('input:text').attr('id');
            var getID = ids.split('_');
            var getName = getID[0];
            var getName2 = getID[1];
            $(this).parent().find('input:text').attr('id',getName + '_' + getName2 + '_' + cnt);
            $(this).parent().find('input:text').attr('name',getName + '_' + getName2 + '_' + cnt);
        })
        cnt++;
    })
}
$(".addnewrow").click(function() {
    cnt++;
    $("#tab2").append('<div class="newrow'+cnt+'"><div align="right" class="delrow" data-id="'+cnt+'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning mright mtop"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div><div class="col-md-3"><label>First name</label>\
    <input id="bill_first_'+cnt+'" class="form-control" name="bill_first_'+cnt+'" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Provide First Name" placeholder="Firstname"/>\
    </div></div>');
});
</script>
```

In the above, I aso want to add a textfield where i can keep record of the added fields like

1,2,3,4 in a textfield

Like here is my Initial HTML on Page

```
<div id="tab2">
            <h2>Billing Information</h2>
        <div align="right" class="col-lg-12"><span class="addnewrow"><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default">Add New</a></span></div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>First name</label>
            <input id="bill_first_1" class="form-control" name="bill_first_1" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Provide First Name" placeholder="Firstname" />
            </div>

    <input type="text" name="listaddress_bill" id="listaddress_bill" value="1">
        </div>
```

for every added and deleted, i want my this input field to be updated with correct counter:

```
listaddress_bill
```

I tried adding some code but that did not worked:

```
var vals = cnt;
    $.each(function() {
        if(vals) vals += '^';
        vals += $(this).val();
    });
    $("#listaddress_bill").val(vals);
```

the above code is added just after the `cnt++` in the `addnewrow` functions

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is run `cnt++` **after** `$("#tab2").append()`, rather than before:

```js
var cnt = 1;
$("body").on("click", ".delrow", function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $('.newrow' + id).remove();
  cnt--;
  resetStuff();
});

function resetStuff() {
  cnt = 2;
  $(".delrow").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().attr('class', 'newrow' + cnt);
    $(this).attr('data-id', cnt);
    $(this).parent().find('input:text').each(function() {
      var ids = $(this).parent().find('input:text').attr('id');
      var getID = ids.split('_');
      var getName = getID[0];
      var getName2 = getID[1];
      $(this).parent().find('input:text').attr('id', getName + '_' + getName2 + '_' + cnt);
      $(this).parent().find('input:text').attr('name', getName + '_' + getName2 + '_' + cnt);
    })
    cnt++;
  })
}
$(".addnewrow").click(function() {
  $("#tab2").append('<div class="newrow' + cnt + '"><div align="right" class="delrow" data-id="' + cnt + '"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning mright mtop"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div><div class="col-md-3"><label>First name</label>\
    <input id="bill_first_' + cnt + '" class="form-control" name="bill_first_' + cnt + '" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Provide First Name" placeholder="Firstname"/>\
    </div></div>');
  cnt++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab2">
  <h2>Billing Information</h2>
  <div align="right" class="col-lg-12"><span class="addnewrow"><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default">Add New</a></span></div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label>First name</label>
    <input id="bill_first_1" class="form-control" name="bill_first_1" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Provide First Name" placeholder="Firstname" />
  </div>

  <input type="text" name="listaddress_bill" id="listaddress_bill" value="1">
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: but with that change, now the very first item has started from 1, before it was starting from 2 which i according to my code was good, but it happens only 1 time, after i keep on adding and delete again couple of them and again add few, it corrects itself, but first time, it starts with 1 which conficts with main form fields having same value

Comment: Also, I want to append these values to a textfield  as comma seperated and remove when i remove an block of the div, i want this textfield to be active live so i can see what is added and what is getting removed

Comment: The First Problem seems to be Fixed which is counter issues,. This I fixed by changing the global var to start from 2 and then increment is happening correctly